# replacing fields from json formating using easier methodology in Qt 5.7 using QVariantMaps

Tags: c++, qt

I have 3 variantMaps created from JSON and I would like to substitute
for example all 3 things from 3d with 2nd and than second to first to the properties.

```
    QVariantMap wholeMapToChange;         //1.          
    QVariantMap propertiesMapToChange;    //2.
    QVariantMap cmdMap;                   //3.
```

1st contain this JSON data but in map:

```
{
  properties { 
       "A": true,  
       "B": true,  
       "fieldName": "ewfqfqewf",
       "C": false, 
       "fieldPassword": "451541611", 
       "isBtnSignOnClicked": true
   },
  type: "xyz"
}
```

2nd contain this JSON data but in map:

```
{ 
"A": true,  
"B": true,  
"fieldName": "ewfqfqewf",
"C": false, 
"fieldPassword": "451541611", 
"isBtnSignOnClicked": true
}
```

3d contain this JSON data but in map:

```
{ 
"fieldName": "nick",
"fieldPassword": "0000", 
"isBtnSignOnClicked": true   
}
```

What I see as a possibility for substituing 3 with 2 is to create cycle

```
for (QVariantMap::const_iterator it = propertiesMapToChange.begin(); it != propertiesMapToChange.end(); ++it){

   for (QVariantMap::const_iterator itt = cmdMap.begin(); itt != cmdMap.end(); ++itt){

         ///here would be the comparig... 

    }
  }
```

But I dont think this is good solution... I would like to ask you for advice or opinion, whether its correct, or there exist better way to do that.

Thx

Comment: Note: your 1st JSON example is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the right solution if the maps aren't too big, since the cost is N*M. But it is a premature pessimization. You should implement the loop to have N+M cost: after all, the maps are sorted, so you only need to iterate each map once.

A complete example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/json-map-iter-39979440
#include <QtCore>

QVariantMap replaceMap(QVariantMap dst, const QVariantMap & src) {
    auto dit = dst.begin();
    auto sit = src.begin();
    while (dit != dst.end() && sit != src.end()) {
        if (sit.key() < dit.key()) {
            ++ sit;
            continue;
        }
        if (dit.key() < sit.key()) {
            ++ dit;
            continue;
        }
        Q_ASSERT(sit.key() == dit.key());
        dit.value() = sit.value();
        ++ sit;
        ++ dit;
    }
    return dst;
}

int main() {
    auto json1 = QJsonDocument::fromJson({R"ZZ({
     "properties":{
        "A":true,
        "B":true,
        "fieldName":"ewfqfqewf",
        "C":false,
        "fieldPassword":"451541611",
        "isBtnSignOnClicked":true
     },
     "type":"xyz"
     })ZZ"}).toVariant().value<QVariantMap>();

    auto json2 = QJsonDocument::fromJson({R"ZZ({
     "A":true,
     "B":true,
     "fieldName":"ewfqfqewf",
     "C":false,
     "fieldPassword":"451541611",
     "isBtnSignOnClicked":true
     })ZZ"}).toVariant().value<QVariantMap>();

    auto json3 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(
    {R"ZZ({
     "fieldName":"nick",
     "fieldPassword":"0000",
     "isBtnSignOnClicked":true
     })ZZ"}).toVariant().value<QVariantMap>();

    json2 = replaceMap(json2, json3);
    auto props = replaceMap(json1["properties"].value<QVariantMap>(), json2);
    json1["properties"] = props;

    qDebug() << QJsonDocument::fromVariant(json1).toJson().constData();
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "A": true,
        "B": true,
        "C": false,
        "fieldName": "nick",
        "fieldPassword": "0000",
        "isBtnSignOnClicked": true
    },
    "type": "xyz"
}
```